# Drupal: change $link->text depending on a specific node in flag.tpl.php?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, task-parallel-library

I’m taking over a Drupal site where I’m currently working on changing the text (the $link_text) depending on the current, active node.

Because I’ve taken over the development of the site I haven’t been involved in the actual development and therefore can change the code to much because the site is already in production and pretty much working except some small issues, where this is one of them.

I’m working in the flag.tpl.php file where I want to say:

```
$nodetype = $node->type;
if($nodetype == 'image'){$link_text='recommend image';}else{$link_text='recommend post';}
```

But unfortunately the flag.tpl.php doesn’t support $node->type selection so I was wondering if there was a workaround for this?

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

However, if you are talking about dynamically changing the text of hyperlinks, I don't think you can do that except by using jquery.

If I have guessed correctly, you just need to perform a check to see if a link has a class of active and use the text() function to change the text of the link.

Hope I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the $node variable is available in flag.tpl.php

Try adding `$node = node_load(arg(1));` before `$nodetype = $node->type;`

That might do the trick.

Comment: Hi Gokul, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work but gives me this error: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /flag.tpl.php on line 48

Comment: Oops you should change $arg(1) to arg(1)